KMP Compose - How to handle the iOS keyboard
In KMP Compose, how do you handle the iOS keyboard? In Android, there is a button to close the keyboard manually, but it does not appear on the iOS side. If I used SwiftUI, I can program the button to appear, but since I am using KMP Compose, I don't have that ability.
Does anyone know how to add a button for closing the keyboard on the iOS side? Specifically, I am using the num pad.

You can set a listener on your background / surrounding area. When the user taps on it, close the keyboard.
Yes - it's naff. But that's Apple for you. Apparently Apple users are used to closing the keyboard in this way. Can't say I've ever seen a close button on an Apple keyboard. When I last programmed in Swift I replaced the Apple keyboard with a third-party one that worked a million times better. Not sure how doable that is in KMP.
